# Display search results in div while typing with javascript on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, search

I am in the process of duplicating a wordpress website. The person who created this site did not use wordpress properly (he just put a bunch of html code into the text editor instead of creating the site from scratch). Everything is duplicated onto the new site perfectly except the search feature. I can't seem to get that to work. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can duplicate it?

Basically when a user starts typing into the search box (the green rectangle), after at least three letters are typed, the results begin to display under the form, filtering as the user types more letters. I can prevent the default action of the form so that a user doesn't hit enter to submit the form. If there isn't a plugin to do this, perhaps there is a php/javascript way where I can: 
call a function in php or javascript/jquery every time a character is entered into the search field that: 
   -- searches the wordpress posts of a custom post type category for a string and return all titles that contain that string. I can use the title of the post or since I'm using advanced custom fields I can search by the name field of that.
   -- displays that information under the form

The page I am trying to duplicate is here: 
http://www.jessicadesmond.com/sr/our-team/

**EDIT**

```
    function getElementByClass (className, parent) {
  parent || (parent = document);
  var descendants= parent.getElementsByTagName('*'), i=-1, e, result=[];
  while (e=descendants[++i]) {
    ((' '+(e['class']||e.className)+' ').indexOf(' '+className+' ') > -1) && result.push(e);
  }
  return result;
}


function gid(a_id) {
    return document.getElementById (a_id)   ;
}

function close_all(){// hide all divs
    var searchers = getElementByClass("search-title", "");

    for (i=0;i<searchers.length; i++) {// to simplify the story I have here the hardcoded number of elements. In real life make it better.
        var o = gid("user_"+i);
        if (o) { //just to make sure this object really exists
            o.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}


function find_my_div(){ // find and show
    close_all(); // close previous searhc results
    var o_edit = gid("edit_search");
    var str_needle = edit_search.value;
    str_needle = str_needle.toUpperCase();

    var searchers = getElementByClass("search-title", "");

    if (str_needle != "") {// we will not search for empty strings
        for (i=0;i<searchers.length; i++) {
        var o = gid("user_"+i);
        var s = gid("title_"+i);
        if (s) { //just to make sure this object really exists
            // we want case insensitive search, so bring the both parts to upper case and compare
            var str_haystack = s.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
            if (str_haystack.indexOf(str_needle) ==-1) {
                // not found, do nothing
            }
            else{
                // yes, we got it, show it
                o.style.display = "block";
            }   
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the HTML/PHP that is displaying the content:

```
<div id="team-search">
    <p>Search for a professional by name, title, or practice</p>
    <form class="team-search" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
        <input name="search" id="edit_search" type="text" class="edit_search" onchange="find_my_div()">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search" class="searchbutton"/>
    </form>
</div>
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'team',
        'taxonomy' => 'employee-type',
        'term' => 'attorneys',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $att_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $att_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $i = 0 ?>
        <div id="listTeam">
            <?
            while ($att_query->have_posts()) : $att_query->the_post(); 
                ?>
                <div style="display: none;" class="entryTeam" id="user_<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <div class="teamTitle">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo the_field('photo'); ?>" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
                        </a>
                        <p class="search-title" id="title_<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                        <p><em><?php echo the_field('tagline'); ?></em></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php 
                $i++;
                endwhile; 
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice, at that site they do not implement dynamic request to the server (AJAX) as you type in. (You can monitor network traffic with Chrome's dev tools). They simply sort the data according to the input.

Let's see their source code.
Search for "entryTeam" and you will see the structure of all the elements - all those persons. And you see they all have `style="display: none;"`.

And here is their search function

```
function listFilter(headerTeam, list) {
var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterformTeam","action":"#"}),
    input = $("<input>").attr({"id":"filterinputTeam","class":"filterinputTeam","type":"text"});
jQuery(form).append(input).appendTo(headerTeam);

jQuery(input)
  .change( function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if(filter) {
      $(list).find(".teamTitle:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
      $(list).find(".teamTitle:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
    } else {
      $(list).find(".entryTeam").hide();
    }
    return false;
  })
.keyup( function () {

     if(this.value.length > 2){  
     $(".allTeam").hide();
     $('#allTeam').css('z-index', -999);
     $(this).change();
    }else{
   $(list).find(".entryTeam").hide();
   $(".allTeam").show();
   $('#allTeam').css('z-index', 999);
    }
});
}
```

So, just replicate it :)

---

Now, here's my piece of code, no jQuery, works fine, enjoy:

```
<div id="user_0" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Alex<br>CEO</div>
<div id="user_1" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Ben<br>CTO</div>
<div id="user_2" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Collin<br>VP R&D</div>
<div id="user_3" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Daniel<br>Office manager</div>
<div id="user_4" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Edward<br>Butcher</div>
<div id="user_5" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Gerrald<br>Baker</div>
<div id="user_6" style="padding:10px; display:none;" >Henry<br>Candle stick maker</div>

<br>
    <input type="text" id= "edit_search">
    <input type="button" onClick="javascript: find_my_div();" value="Find">
    <input type="button" onClick="javascript: close_all();" value="Hide">


<script>

function gid(a_id) {
    return document.getElementById (a_id)   ;
}

  function close_all(){// hide all divs

    for (i=0;i<7; i++) {// to simplify the story I have here the hardcoded number of elements. In real life make it better.
        var o = gid("user_"+i);
        if (o) { //just to make sure this object really exists
            o.style.display = "none";
        }
}

  }


  function find_my_div(){ // find and show
    close_all(); // close previous searhc results

    var o_edit = gid("edit_search");
    var str_needle = edit_search.value;
    str_needle = str_needle.toUpperCase();

    if (str_needle != "") {// we will not search for empty strings
        for (i=0;i<7; i++) {
        var o = gid("user_"+i);
        if (o) { //just to make sure this object really exists
            // we want case insensitive search, so bring the both parts to upper case and compare
            var str_haystack = o.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
            if (str_haystack.indexOf(str_needle) ==-1) {
                // not found, do nothing
            }
            else{
                // yes, we got it, show it
                o.style.display = "block";
                }   
            }
        }
    }

  }
</script>
```

---

Test it here: http://btlr.com/code/js_search.html

Comment: What part of the html do I copy and what part is generated by this code? More specifically, do I put in the `display: none` myself? So if I were to take all of that html and this javascript and put it in the page, theoretically it will work?

Comment: Theoretically, you can dig in their code and find what you need, just do not forget to include jQuery and use Chrome -> dev tools to examine their code.

But it'd prefer to do it on my own, will update my post in 20 min, jus want to prepare my own code.

Comment: This is excellent. One question: This works when I press enter. Is there a way to get this to work using something onchange so it just shows up as the user types? I have pasted the modified code above.

Comment: This actually works when you click away from the textbox as well. So I guess I just need it to happen whether you click away or not.

Comment: In fact, this works when you click the button. What you probably need is to add an onKeyUp event for the edit box. In this case the search will take place each time you type in a new character or delete it.

Simply add it to the input field:

    <input type="text" id="edit_search" onkeyup="javascript: find_my_div();">

I updated my example here:
http://btlr.com/code/js_search.html

Comment: I know we aren't supposed to reply with thanks, but I can't thank you enough. You don't know how much you helped me. Thank you so much.

Comment: you are very welcome. simply follow me in twitter, details on my web site. Cheers :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38198/discussion-between-btlr-com-and-danielle-zarcaro)